# What is the difference between static pod and DaemonSet?

Tags: kubernetes

Can the relationship between static pod and DaemonSet be analogue to the one between pod and RelicaSet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#static-pods)

> Unlike DaemonSet, static Pods cannot be managed with kubectl or other
>   Kubernetes API clients. Static Pods do not depend on the apiserver,
>   making them useful in cluster bootstrapping cases. Also, static Pods
>   may be deprecated in the future.

Pod and Replicaset both can be managed by kubectl or other Kubernetes API clients and depend on the apiserver.

So there is no analogy between these.